# Trying to get the modal working in React Native

Tags: react-native

Attempting to get the modal working on my react native app. I want the more page to display a modal of more options. I have made the following attempt in regards putting the modal in the more menu page. The error I am currently getting is:

[image: It is a nightmare to debug this stuff.]

## MoreMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

class MoreMenu extends Component {

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType={"slide"}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
         <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
          <View>
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
              this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
            }}>
              <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

          </View>
         </View>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(true)
        }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## TabsRoot.JS

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  _changeTab (i) {
    const { changeTab } = this.props
    changeTab(i)
  }
  _renderTabContent (key) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'today':
        return <Home />
      case 'share':
        return <Share />
      case 'savequote':
        return <SaveQuote />
      case 'moremenu':
        return <MoreMenu />
    }
  }
  render () {
    const tabs = this.props.tabs.tabs.map((tab, i) => {
      return (
        <TabBarIOS.Item key={tab.key}
          icon={tab.icon}
          selectedIcon={tab.selectedIcon}
          title={tab.title}
          onPress={() => this._changeTab(i)}
          selected={this.props.tabs.index === i}>
          {this._renderTabContent(tab.key)}
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      )
    })
    return (
      <TabBarIOS tintColor='black'>
        {tabs}
      </TabBarIOS>
    )
  }
}

export default Tabs
```

Comment: Is this part correct  `const tabs = this.props.tabs.tabs.map`? Or should it be this.props.tabs.map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to `export` `MoreMenu` Component. and you use `MoreMenu` Component in `TabsRoot.js`.

pls add following line at the end of `MoreMenu.js`

```
export default MoreMenu
```